# Page is part of the declarations of 2 modules: Error in ionic build prod

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I run **npm run ionic:build** I am able to build successfully. But When I run **npm run ionic:build --prod** I am getting following error message.

```
Error: Type PatientDetailPage in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.ts is 
            part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/app/app.module.ts and 
            PatientDetailPageModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.module.ts! 
            Please consider moving PatientDetailPage in 
            /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.ts to a higher module that imports 
            AppModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/app/app.module.ts and PatientDetailPageModule in 
            /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.module.ts. You can also create a new 
            NgModule that exports and includes PatientDetailPage in 
            /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.ts then import that NgModule in 
            AppModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/app/app.module.ts and PatientDetailPageModule in 
            /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.module.ts. 
Error: Type PatientDetailPage in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/app/app.module.ts and PatientDetailPageModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.module.ts! Please consider moving PatientDetailPage in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/app/app.module.ts and PatientDetailPageModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes PatientDetailPage in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/app/app.module.ts and PatientDetailPageModule in /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/src/pages/patient-detail/patient-detail.module.ts.
    at syntaxError (/home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1550:34)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (/home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14655:31)
    at /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14543:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14534:54)
    at addNgModule (/home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23050:58)
    at /home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23061:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _createNgModules (/home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23060:26)
    at analyzeNgModules (/home/shiva/Ionic/af2-lists/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22935:14)
```

I understand that I am loading same modules multiple times, But could not understand how to remove them.

my app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireOfflineModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
   // PatientDetailPage

  ],
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    PatientDetailPage
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    PatientDetailPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    //AngularFireModule,
    //Storage,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ],
   bootstrap: [IonicApp],
})
```

patient-detail.module.ts is

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PatientDetailPage } from './patient-detail';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PatientDetailPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(PatientDetailPage),
  ]

})
export class PatientDetailPageModule {

}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a basic error of angular. You can see the issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10646#issuecomment-253275045). So the answer that is *accepted* till now is use share module. You can do like this:
 - Create a `share.module.ts`
 - `Import`, `declaration` and `export` your component in this `share.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import {SharedComponentA} from "./SharedComponentA";
import {SharedComponentB} from "./SharedComponentB";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
      SharedComponentA,
      SharedComponentB

    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    exports: [
      SharedComponentA,
      SharedComponentB
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

- If you want to use your component in a **Ionic Page(lazy load page)**, import share module in the module of that Ionic page:

```
import {SharedModule } from './SharedModule';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule    
        //..
    ],
    //..
})
```

- If you want to use your component in other component or **no lazy load** page, import share module in your **app.module.ts** like above.
See more about [ngModule](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a component as an entryComponent within a module you do not need to declare it within the Module. Try removing `PatientDetailPage` from the `declarations` on your `app.module.ts`.

So the best way to do this in my opinion is to `export` your `PatientDetailPage` out from your `PatientDetailModule` and import the `PatientDetailModule` into your App Module.

**App Module**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireOfflineModule,
    PatientDetailModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
   // PatientDetailPage

  ],
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    PatientDetailPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    //AngularFireModule,
    //Storage,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ],
   bootstrap: [IonicApp],
})
```

**Patient Module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PatientDetailPage } from './patient-detail';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PatientDetailPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(PatientDetailPage),
  ],
  exports: [
    PatientDetailPage
  ]

})
export class PatientDetailPageModule {

}
```

Comment: If I remove PatienctDetailPage, I can only see blank page in my browser.

Comment: I updated my answer. The best thing in my opinion is to import your PatientDetailModule into your App Module and export your PatientDetailPage component.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare anything on `app.module.ts` about `PatientDetailPageModule`.So remove all references to it.If you need to use `PatientDetailPageModule` module inside another component then just `import` like below.

*another.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
     imports: [
        PatientDetailPageModule,
      ], 
})
```

Use [**Cordova builds**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/):

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```