# ionic 3 angular Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

i generated a blank app using ionic start. That ran fine.

Now i added a new page called opty using 
ionic g page opty.

Created a navigation using navPush from home.html to opty.html on click of button. Works great.

Now, I added a component using:
ionic g component opty-header

All fine until here. Now, if include this in the opty.html as

it ends up with error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'opty-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'opty-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'opty-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

<ion-content padding>
  [ERROR ->]<opty-header></opty-header>
</ion-content>
"): ng:///AppModule/OptyPage.html@16:2 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
'opty-header'
```

My opty.module.ts looks like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { OpportunitiesPage } from './opportunities';

import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OpportunitiesPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(OpportunitiesPage),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
})
export class OpportunitiesPageModule {}
```

my components.module.ts looks like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OptyHeaderComponent } from './opty-header/opty-header';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [OptyHeaderComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [OptyHeaderComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

As opty.module.ts is explictly importing the OptyHeaderComponent as well as declared so I am failing to understand how to fix it.

Comment: you have `components.module.ts`, so just import it to your `opty.module.ts`. Don't import component again.

Comment: not sure how do u import a module to another. please give an example

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166922/4254681). If still face error please let me know

Comment: where do i create share.module.ts ? and any specific cli command etc. to do that?

Comment: You can use your `components.module.ts` instead of `share.module.ts`. It is just a name. Please see [this](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule) to better understanding

Comment: Just create a new file and name it to share.module.ts. You can place it any where.

Comment: OK I am going to try using components.module.ts to see if it works

Comment: i modified but i have no luck. see the modified code in my question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in your `components.module.ts` file you are declaring and exporting the `OptyHeaderComponent`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OptyHeaderComponent } from './opty-header/opty-header';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [OptyHeaderComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [OptyHeaderComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Now in the `opty.module.ts` file just import the `ComponentsModule`, like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { OptyPage } from './opty';

// import the ComponentsModule...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OptyPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(OptyPage),
    ComponentsModule // The ComponentsModule includes the OptyHeaderComponent
  ]
})
export class OptyPageModule { }
```

The lazy load feature is still being improved in Ionic, but this is the recommended way to work with pages and components that are lazy loaded. **So you'd create a single module with all the components (the `ComponentsModule`), and then just import that module in each page module to make it available in that page**.

Comment: You are right. But why need `exports: [    OptyPage   ]`?

Comment: My bad, it's not required at all. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: this is not working at all for me. i modified my question with latest code i have based on your suggestion. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First your components.module needs to list on the imports the class of component module.

**components.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OptyHeaderComponent } from './opty-header/opty-header';
@NgModule({
    imports: [OptyHeaderComponentModule]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Your opty module needs to exports the header component so it can be use in other components

**opty.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { OptyPage } from './opty';

import { OptyHeaderComponent } from '../../components/opty-header/opty-header'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OptyPage,
    OptyHeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(OptyPage)
  ],
  exports: [
    OptyHeaderComponent
  ]
})
```

Comment: this didnt made sense to me. but i still gave it a try and yes it doesnt work