# Angular 2 Ionic 3 - Lazy load pipe module

Tags: angular, ionic2, lazy-loading

In Angular 2+/Ionic 3 how do I lazy load a pipe into a component?

In my example I want to use an OrderBy pipe in my component. Note I do not want my pipes to be be global. 
So far I have done the following but get an 'OrderBy' pipe not found error:

In pipes folder setup a pipe module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppFilterDatePipe } from './app-filter-date';
import { AppFilterDirectoryPipe } from './app-filter-directory';
import { AppFilterShortcutCategoryPipe } from './app-filter-shortcut-category';
import { AppFilterPipe } from './app-filter';
import { AppFormMessageFilterPipe } from './app-form-message-filter';
import { AppTraitPipe } from './app-trait';
import { OrderByPipe } from './order-by';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppFilterDatePipe, 
        AppFilterDirectoryPipe,
        AppFilterShortcutCategoryPipe,
        AppFilterPipe,
        AppFormMessageFilterPipe,
        AppTraitPipe,
        OrderByPipe
    ],
    imports: [],
    exports: [AppFilterDatePipe, 
        AppFilterDirectoryPipe,
        AppFilterShortcutCategoryPipe,
        AppFilterPipe,
        AppFormMessageFilterPipe,
        AppTraitPipe,
        OrderByPipe]
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

Then in the component which I want to use the pipe in, I declare as follows:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { PipesModule } from '../../../pipes/pipes.module';
/**
 * Generated class for the CompanyDirectoryComponent component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html
 * for more info on Angular Components.
 */
@NgModule({
  imports: [ PipesModule ],
  declarations: [ ],
  bootstrap: [ ]
})
@Component({
  selector: 'company-directory',
  templateUrl: 'company-directory.html'
})
export class CompanyDirectoryComponent {

   // Component code goes here
}
```

What am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your CompanyDirectoryComponent lazy load?

Comment: No its not, CompanyDirectoryComponent is defined globally. I am guessing CompanyDirectoryComponent has to be lazy loaded for this to work?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159788/page-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules-error-in-ionic-build-prod/46166922#46166922) you can find the solution