# Multiple component in shared.module.ts Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

i am new to ionic and recently i tried to create a shared component so that i can sort of remove duplicate coding of same content on different page. It consist of a notification bar and a panel that have a login/signup button. I am able to display the notification bar and the login panel on pages that i want but i am unable to call the function of the login/signup button.

Whenever i click the login/signup button, it will said presentLoginModal() is not a function. Below are my code.

Hope someone can advice me on this. Thanks.

**shared.module.ts**

```
            import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
            import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
            import {NotificationComponent} from '../notification/notification';
            import {NonLoginComponent} from '../nonlogin/nonlogin';

            @NgModule({
              imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(NotificationComponent),IonicPageModule.forChild(NonLoginComponent)],
              declarations: [NotificationComponent, NonLoginComponent],
              exports: [NotificationComponent, NonLoginComponent]
            }) export class SharedModule {}
```

**nonlogin.ts**

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
        import {Login} from '../login/login';
        import {Register} from '../register/register'
        @IonicPage()
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-nonlogin',
          templateUrl: './nonlogin.html'
        })
        export class NonLoginComponent {

           constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

           presentLoginModal() {
           let loginModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Login, {showBackdrop: true, enableBackdropDismiss: true},{cssClass: 'logon'});
           loginModal.present();
         }

           presentRegisterModal(){
           let registerModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Register, {showBackdrop: true, enableBackdropDismiss: true},{cssClass: 'register'});
           registerModal.present();
         }

        }
```

**notification.ts**

```
            import { Component } from '@angular/core';
            import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

            @Component({
              selector: 'app-notification',
              templateUrl: './notification.html'
            })
            export class NotificationComponent {

                constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}


            }
```

**nonlogin.html**

```
        <div class="toppanel"><div class="leftside"><img class="companylogo" 
       src="../../assets/imgs/logo.jpg"></div><div class="rightside">
       <button tappable class="login" ion-button 
         (click)="presentLoginModal()">LOG IN</button><button tappable 
       class="signup" ion-button (click)="presentRegisterModal()">SIGN 
        UP</button></div></div>
```

**home.html**

```
       <ion-content>

       <app-notification></app-notification>

       <app-nonlogin></app-nonlogin>
       </ion-content>
```

Comment: In your `shared.module.ts` just `imports: [IonicPageModule]`, no need `forChild`

Comment: Hey @Duannx, thanks alot for your help, it solve the issue.

Comment: Glad i could help :-)

Comment: Hi Duannx, i intend to call the <app-notification> inside a page that is displayed using modal controller. It show the following error.

    Template parse errors: 'app-notification' is not a known element: 1. If 'app-notification' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]


Wonder if you know what is the issue? Isit the shared component cannot be used in pages that are view in modal controller?

Comment: Shared component definitely can be used in modal controller. If your modal is an `IonicPage`, import `SharedModule` in `.module.ts` file of that page. If your modal is a component, import `SharedModule` in `app.module.ts`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166922/4254681) to know more

Comment: Hi Duannx, thanks for your advice, it work perfectly. =D

Comment: You are welcome!